# SQLAlchemy and empty columns

Tags: python, database-design, sqlalchemy

When I try to insert a new record into the database using SQLAlchemy and I don't fill out all values, it tries to insert them as "None" (instead of omitting them). It then complains about "can't be null" errors. Is there a way to have it just omit columns from the sql query if I also omitted them when declaring the instance?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a database schema issue, not an SQLAlchemy issue. If your database schema has a column which cannot be NULL, you must put something (i.e. not None) into there. Or change your schema to allow NULL in those columns.

Wikipedia has an article [about NULL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)) and an article which describes [non-NULL constraints](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_Constraint#NOT_NULL_Constraint)

Comment: Agree to disagree, I'm currently having the exact same issue as the question: the column is defined as `timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. The object added has not set this attribute, but SQLAlchemy tries to insert a `NULL` value anyway

Answer (score 70):

To add to the answer from Ali A, this means you need to have `nullable=True` in your column definition, so that NULL is allowed in the column. For example:

```
email_address = Column(String, nullable=True)
```

[SQLAlchemy docs for Tables and Columns](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#accessing-tables-and-columns), excerpt from v1.2 doc:

> nullable – When set to False, will cause the “NOT NULL” phrase to be
>   added when generating DDL for the column. When True, will normally
>   generate nothing (in SQL this defaults to “NULL”), except in some very
>   specific backend-specific edge cases where “NULL” may render
>   explicitly. Defaults to True unless primary_key is also True, in which
>   case it defaults to False. This parameter is only used when issuing
>   CREATE TABLE statements.

Comment: this more directly answers the question

Comment: I've set `nullable=True`, but an IntegrityError is raised. Saying that there is a NOT NULL constraint.

Answer (score 0):

In case the default are declared in the schema (but with a `NOT NULL` check), you can declare them with a [`FetchedValue`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#marking-implicitly-generated-values-timestamps-and-triggered-columns)

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import FetchedValue


class Foo(Base):
    date_created = Column(DateTime, server_default=FetchedValue())
```